# google maps api 3 infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

Hi I'm trying to use this code for a project that I'm doing with the Google Maps API.

I wonder if anyone know how can I add a var that call a url link below the streetview in the infowindow.

```
function initialize() {

    // Create the map 
    // No need to specify zoom and center as we fit the map further down.
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        streetViewControl: false
    });

    // Create the shared infowindow with two DIV placeholders
    // One for a text string, the other for the StreetView panorama.
    var content = document.createElement("DIV");
    var title = document.createElement("DIV");
    content.appendChild(title);
    title.style.color ="gray";
    title.style.height = "30px";
    var streetview = document.createElement("DIV");
    content.appendChild(streetview);
    streetview.style.width = "260px";
    streetview.style.height = "160px";
    streetview.style.background ="red";
    var aqui = document.createElement("DIV");
    content.appendChild(aqui);
    aqui.style.color ="gray";
    aqui.style.height = "30px";
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: content
    });



    // Define the list of markers.
    // This could be generated server-side with a script creating the array.
    var markers = [
        { lat: 0, lng: -0, name: "name", icon: "icon.png" },
        { lat: 0, lng: -0, name: "name", icon: "icon.png" },
        { lat: 0, lng: -0, name: "name", icon: "icon.png"  },
        { lat: 0, lng: -0, name: "name", icon: "icon.png"}
    ];

    // Create the markers
    for (index in markers) 
        addMarker(markers[index]);

    function addMarker(data) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
        icon: data.icon,
            map: map,
            title: data.name
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            openInfoWindow(marker);
        });
    }

    // Zoom and center the map to fit the markers
    // This logic could be conbined with the marker creation.
    // Just keeping it separate for code clarity.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (index in markers) {
        var data = markers[index];
        bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng));
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    // Handle the DOM ready event to create the StreetView panorama
    // as it can only be created once the DIV inside the infowindow is loaded in the DOM.
    var panorama = null;
    var pin = new google.maps.MVCObject();
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infowindow, "domready", function() {
        panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(streetview, {
            navigationControl: false,
            enableCloseButton: false,
            addressControl: true,
            linksControl: false,
            visible: true
        });
        panorama.bindTo("position", pin);
    });

    // Create a StreetViewService to be able to check
    // if a given LatLng has a corresponding panorama.
    var service = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

    // Set the infowindow content and display it on marker click.
    // Use a 'pin' MVCObject as the order of the domready and marker click events is not garanteed.
    function openInfoWindow(marker) {
        title.innerHTML = marker.getTitle();
        streetview.style['visibility'] = 'hidden';
        service.getPanoramaByLocation(marker.getPosition(), 50, function(result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
                pin.set("position", marker.getPosition());
                streetview.style['visibility'] = '';
            }
        })
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
}
```

Comment: What "url link below the streetview in the infowindow"?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Im trying to put something like a text field with a url below the street view in the infowindow. something like this: http://www.weareprologo.com/test/example.png

Comment: Is your question about how to add a string under the panorama in the infowindow (which it sounds like you know how to do) or about how to get a URL that corresponds to the streetview panorama in question?